# Trying to list cities in a county using intersection

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am trying to configure a popup in arcgis online which finds all major US cities within a county and lists them.  I have the US Counties and Major US Cities layers.  I am trying to create an expression in arcade that intersects these two layers, then returns a list of cities within the county.
My code is below:

```
var citiesInCty = Intersects($feature, FeatureSetByName($map, "USA Major Cities")) //This intersects the county layer with the cities (I know this works correctly.)
var i = 1

//Here I am attempting to create and populate array with city names 
//There is a field in USA Major Cities called "NAME"

for (var f in citiesInCty){ 
   if (i == 1){
     var City = Array(1, f.NAME)
     i = 2
   }
   else  {
     City = Splice(City, f.NAME)
     i += 1  
   }    
}

return City
```

The code returns nothing.

As I test, I created a null array and this displays fine in my popup, but the array created with the above code does not.
I've tried several different methods of creating this array, so far none of which worked!

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The code above actually works.  For some reason when I restarted my computer it started working.